# What system call does javascript's `new Date()` uses?

Tags: javascript, node.js

My server's `/etc/localtime` was in GMT, so I changed it back to CST by linking it to the different timezone file.

After changing that, when I type `date` in bash, it says correct time in CST format.

However, when I run a serverside javascript program using node.js, it still says time in GMT timezone.

```
console.log(new Date());
```

Do I have to reboot the server? What system call does javascript's (V8) uses for `new Date()`?

Do I have to recompile `node.js?` I will appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

---

**Note**

I realized that getHours() and getMinutes() will return the hours and minutes of localtime. It is just that `new Date()` will always return date format in terms of GMT. Therefore, just use getHours() and getMinutes() method to get the time in local date format.

```
var p = new Date(); // in GMT
p.getHours();       // in hours in local timezone (CST)
p.getMinutes();     // in minutes in local timezone (CST)
```

So, you don't really have to set anything and calculate anything.

Comment: yeah I just realized that getHours() and getMinutes() will return the hours and minutes based on the localtime.

Comment: I modified this answer for anyone who may come and see this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You have to restart programs for them to notice the new timezone, try that if you have not already. The timezone can also be overridden with env variables, so check those as well.

Comment: I restarted the node program, but still no changes. I typed `env` to check environmental variables, but there is no sign of timezone setting in there.

Comment: Sorry, I have no other ideas. But I'm curious what `getTimezoneOffset()` returns.